# Update old git repo from Subversion

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I started working with gSOAP and found a git version of the source code in [Github](https://github.com/stoneyrh/gSOAP). But it turned out this repo hasn't been updated for 10 years. Since it's the top entry for "gsoap source code" in Google I wanted to update it, but I have no idea how it was originally created. Is it possible to update it using git svn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38706530/264822 but had to play around with it a few times to get this to work.

1. Fork the repo in Github.
2. `git clone` my copy of the repo from Github.
3. `git checkout -b github` to make a copy of master.
4. `git branch -d master` to delete master.
5. Edit .git/config to add the [official Subversion URL](https://sourceforge.net/p/gsoap2/code):

```
    [svn-remote "master"]
       url = https://svn.code.sf.net/p/gsoap2/code/
       fetch = :refs/heads/master
```

6. `git svn fetch master` to migrate the Subversion history into master.
7. `git checkout master`
8. `git rebase github` to rebase the original Github history onto the Subversion history.
9. `git branch -d github` clean up.
10. `git push --set-upstream origin master` force push the new history.
11. Create a PR from my updated repo back to the original Github repo.

There may be a simpler way of doing this (e.g. pulling the Subversion history into a branch) but this method works.